# JavaBeans: Can not read Variables from JavaBeans class

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

i got a simple programm that begins on an input form where the user fills in 3 numbers. The form action refers to a controller servlet where i store the data in the Bean class with the setter methods I have defined.

```
number.setNumber1(Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("number1")));
```

Till now I stored the Number object in the request with

```
request.setAttribute("numbers", number);
```

and forwarded it to the output page where i could get it with ${numbers.biggestNumber ( getter-Method that simply determines the biggest Number) }. A tutorial i am using says I could also get the data directly from the Bean by using this piece of code:

```
<jsp:useBean id="num" scope="session" class="model.Numbers"/>
<c:out value="${num.biggestNumber}/>
```

but somehow the Bean uses another object of the Numbers-class. I see the advantage of this technique, because I dont have to put the Numbers object into the request. Can someone tell me how I can use the same Numbers object I stored the data before?

I already read that I shouldnt use "jsp:setProperty..." to store the data on the input page, but if i cant get the information i wrote manually to the Bean, I have to ask myself why I should use the JSP JavaBeans annotation at all.

I used the search function but could not find an answer suitable to my question, or maybe I am just not experienced enough to get them in a more advanced context... Any help would be welcome

Comment: how are you redirecting your request to another page ? using response.redirect... ???

Comment: No, i am using                                                                         dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Output.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);

Comment: after lot of try i get what mistake i did, and solved it. see my edited answer. please, if you are satiesfied with my answer then accept+upvote to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using this one,

```
request.setAttribute("numbers", number);
```

And using requestDispacher redirecting then at target page you can do likewise,

into JSP file :

```
<jsp:useBean id="numbers" scope="request" class="model.Numbers"/>
<c:out value="${numbers.biggestNumber}/>
```

> Here,
>
> 1. you did with wrong scope=session, means you are putting value into 'request' scope and try to pull it from session is wrong.
> 2. also maintain name of attribute 'same' while putting/getting from scope. here, name="numbers" maintain while putting/getting

Comment: I can use <c:out value="${numbers.biggestNumber}" default="<fehler>" escapeXml="true"/> when I put the data into the request first, but I tried to avoid doing this. I set the data to the JavaBean aswell and would prefer to just get it from there without being dependent on the request. Sorry if the question is not clear, i am not a native english speaker

Answer (score 0):

Okay my mistake was that I thought JavaBeans-Jsp-Tags would save time and code. Indeed I had to create a HttpSession-Object that stores the ID of the used JavaBean

```
HttpSession sess = request.getSession(true);
sess.setAttribute("number", number);
```

Now the JavaBean-Tag in my Output.jsp knows which object to use (the one created in the Input.jsp). As far as I do understand now, the only advantage of the JavaBean-Jsp-Tag above normal Parameters added to the Request is that I can use the Bean-Class in the whole Session and am not dependend on the Request-Object.